# Jquery - Removing appended code not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have problem with removing appended code.
Try add some div's and check results.
When you try dblclicked on new div, he won't be removed.

HTML:

```
<input id="val" name="value" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="ok" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

Script:

```
$("div[id^='block_']").on('dblclick', function() {
 $(this).remove();
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
 if ( $('#val').val().length > 0 )
 {
  $('#content').append('<div id="block_'+ $('#val').val() +'">'+ $('#val').val() +'</div>');

  $('#val').val('');
 }
});
```

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkRre/2/)
I use jquery 2.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element is not there when you are binding the click event. Use delegeted event :

```
$('#content').on('dblclick', "div[id^='block_']", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Here all the information you need : http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1):

As your divs are generated dynamically so use event Delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document.body).on('dblclick',"div[id^='block_']", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkRre/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this part in your code?

```
$("div[id^='block_']").on('dblclick', function() {
 $(this).remove();
});
```

If you're doing this because you want to select the ID of a div tag as the selector you don't have to do it this way.

For example if you want to remove  you would do this:

```
$("#content").on('dblclick', function() {
 $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

another way would be creating the div and assigning the event before appending it to the dom

```
var div = $('<div id="block_'+ $('#val').val() +'">'+ $('#val').val() +'</div>');

div.on('dblclick',function(){$(this).remove();});
$('#content').append(div);
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkRre/5/)